# Ignore tier 1 rows in Excel pivot tables

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in Excel, and I'm trying to do some calculations on the results. This is all fine and good, but I'm running into a problem due to the grouping of a pivot table.

I have a dataset indicating transaction history for a particular client/patient at a vet clinic. These are reflected by clientID and patient name in my pivot table. I've used a pivot table to group by client then patient to see when the first purchase was made and how many total purchases there have been. I want to then do a calculation on that for each patient.

My problem is here. Excel has all the data for each client grouped in what I'll call "tier 1 results". The only data I want to do the calculation on are the "tier 2 results". These are row 7 and then rows 8-9 in the screenshot below.

[image: Pivot table screenshot]

In effect, I wan to include something in the equation in column F to ignore any bold text, but Excel doesn't appear to be able to do this. VBA is an obvious solution for me, but I'm creating steps for salespeople to use to analyze the data while they're out in the field. We need to keep things as simple as possible. Copying and pasting an in-cell equation is one thing, but using VBA is way over their heads.

Any thoughts on how to ignore the tier 1 results?

Comment: Your client ID appears to always be a number. Have you tried `=IF(ISNUMBER(A4),"",your formula)`

Comment: I did think of that, yes. That's under the assumption that the patient name would NEVER have a number in it. Since we're talking about pets (in the context of a vet clinic), that is a safe assumption but not necessarily guaranteed. I just wanted to find something foolproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pivot table uses compact form layout, where all the groupings appear in one column. You can change that to tabular form to have each group level in its own column. The screenshot shows the difference:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Click a cell in the pivot table and then Pivot table Design ribbon > Report Layout dropdown > Tabular form. There are other settings to get rid of subtotal rows, etc.

Now you can build formulas that take into account only the level that you require. (It is also possible to repeat the pivot group labels for each group level where there are blanks.)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help, all.